# Cantor's nested interval theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Can anyone explain to me how if lim(−)=0, then the intersection of the nested consists of a single point.

I would prefer a proof by contradiction where we suppose we have two points instead of one.

My teacher used epsilon = d/2 where d = b-a (b and a being the two distinct points). Then, he showed that b cannot be in the interval once the original interval approaches zero for epsilon= d/2. He said this is due to the fact that we are considering the distance between b and a is d.

I am totally confused here. I would appreciate if someone can show me all the steps. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, the argument that you wrote in the question is very well-formed, so come back to it over time and see if it starts to make sense later.  I'll give the same argument, just pushing the contradiction back a few steps further.

So we have a collection of real intervals $I_i=[a_i,b_i]$, and we know that $\lim a=\lim b$, and we want to show that $\bigcap I$  is a singleton.  By contradiction, let's assume that there are $x,y\in\bigcap I$ such that $x<y$.  Therefore, for every natural number $i$, $[x,y]\subset I_i=[a_i,b_i]$ (by the definitions of intersection and intervals).  So we have $a_i\le x<y\le b_i$ for all natural numbers.  Since $\delta=y-x>0$ (this is a fundamental notion of what it means for two real numbers to be different), it follows that $b_i-a_i>\delta$ for all natural numbers $i$, and therefore $\lim(b-a)\neq0$.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please tell me how sequences of real numbers and sequences of intervals differ? I believe this is acting as an impediment. I can always picture real numbers as single "dots" getting closer and closer but intervals consist of two numbers and the very thought of intervals getting closer is hard to picture.